# Ember.js - how do I bind a controller in a nested collection?

Tags: ember.js

I'm learning ember.js, I haven't built anything with it yet.

I'm storing my data in model objects and using controllers to act as a glue between the view and the models. A controller has content set to an instance of the model, and the view has a binding to the content in controller (and hence to the model by proxy). Like so:

```
// js
App.MyModel = Ember.Object.extend({foo:''});
App.myController = Ember.Object.create({
    content: App.MyModel.create()
});

// html
{{view Ember.TextInput valueBinding="App.myController"}}
```

So far so good. But I don't know how to apply this paradigm to nested collections:

```
//js
App.ChildController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
App.NestedModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('children', []);
        // Here: I can't give a global name for the content binding, and I don't know how to give a relative one
        this.set('childController', App.ChildController.create({contentBinding: 'children');
    }
});
App.myController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content:[],
    newChild: function() {
        this.pushObject(App.NestedModel.create());
    }
});


// html
{{#collection contentBinding="App.myController"}}
    {{#collection contentBinding="content.childController"}} <!-- nope -->
        {{content.childField}}
    {{/collection}}
{{/collection}}
```

Here's something you can fiddle with: http://jsfiddle.net/DwheG/

What I'm asking is:

1. am I even modeling stuff correctly?
2. how do I bind the child controller's content? Do I have to use a string? Passing in objects (`this`) hasn't worked for me. Is Ember's path resolution algo documented anywhere?
3. how do I bind the nested collection helper to the nested controller?

Comment: haha stackoverflow removed the "Hello, " at the beginning of my question... and hvgotcodes removed the "world" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the source and confirmed that bindings can only be specified with paths.

Ember uses `getPath(root, path)` to resolve paths. `root` is the object to start looking from, and path is a string. The root element can be ommited if the path is global (in which case the root will be set to `window`). So, for instance, `getPath(myController, 'foo.bar')` will return `myController.foo.bar` when evaluated.

So: given that I needed to somehow reference the containing object for my array in order to create the binding, and that there are no built-in facilities to do this, I just added a reference to the containing object in my model. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/CP448/1/